# Angular: Get nativeElement from component

Tags: angular

Is there an easy way to get a nativeElement (or ElementRef) from a component instance? I'm referencing a component from the view like this:

```
@ViewChild(MyComponent) myComponent: MyComponent;
```

I understand that I could get the ElementRef instead of getting MyComponent like so:

```
@ViewChild('my-component', { read: ElementRef}) myComponent: ElementRef;
```

Which is fine if all I needed is an ElementRef, but I actually need the instance of MyComponent but then at some later point I need to down-cast it to ElementRef so that I can access the nativeElement.

Answer (score 5):

As of Angular 9, I'm not aware of a way to get the native element from a component reference. However, it is possible to get both at the same time.

```js
@ViewChild(MyComponent) component: MyComponent;
@ViewChild(MyComponent, { read: ElementRef }) elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;
```