# Synchronize scrolls on 2 divs

Tags: angular

I have 2 scrollable divs with same height, and I would like to sync their scrolls in 2 ways.

I've made a stackblitz here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-0-0-rc-1-sync-scroll?file=src/app/app.component.ts

What I can see is that the scroll event bounces several times and it ends up with a very slow scroll, this is not fluid.

I don't know how to prevent that bouncing, and that when user scrolls in a div, the scroll is reported in the other div and then the event ends there.

I tried with the cdkScrollable but there's a small time between the moment that user scrolls in a div and moment that the scroll is reported to the other div, and I need it to be seamless.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the problem was that when scrolling the first list it updated the second one which also reacted to scroll event and updated the first one. I'm not sure that's what you described in the question, but anyway my idea of fixing it is to check where's cursor right now and update the opposite list. It can be easily done with extra property in the class and updating it on `mouseenter` event.

This is my solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-0-0-rc-1-sync-scroll-m9jqr7?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thx for the trick =)

Comment: I had an issue where one of my elements was actually a native element within a custom component and I was able to pair the 2 answers to get this working. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50396191/angular-get-nativeelement-from-component/61530529#61530529